# Custom page template for category taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I've registered a category taxonomy for my custom post type:

```
function career_create_taxonomy() {

register_taxonomy(
    'career-category',
    'careers',
    array(
        'label' => __( 'Category' ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'career' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
    )
);
}
add_action( 'init', 'career_create_taxonomy' );
```

I wish to create a custom page template for this category. Currently my theme is defaulting to archive.php as expected. I see that the wp documentation states that the you can create any of the following:

```
category-slug.php
category-ID.php
category.php
archive.php
index.php
```

However I can't use slug, or id because I want it to apply to all categories for this custom post type & any future ones. I could style the archive page as desired however, if any other categories default to archive.php they'll be using this specific template which is no good!

So how can I create a page template for each of my categories assigned only to this specific custom post type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hierarchy for custom taxonomies is:

```
taxonomy-$taxonomy-$term.php
taxonomy-$taxonomy.php
taxonomy.php
archive.php
index.php
```

So, if your taxonomy was called `cats`, you could target that specific taxonomy with a template file `taxonomy-cats.php`.

If you wanted to style your tabby cats differently than the rest (because of course you would), then you could use `taxonomy-cats-tabby.php`.

See [wphierarchy.com](https://wphierarchy.com/)

Comment: Hi thanks, i'll give that a go it looks like i got a little confused with the hierarchy. In your example (just so I'm clear) are tabby cats a specific type of cat?

Comment: That's correct.